# How to listen to multiple requests in HTTP server node.js

Tags: node.js, https, server, scale, simultaneous

I have created a server in node.js which does heavy computation and returns the result to the client.

In the debug mode, the API works in the following way(considering simultaneous hit from two devices):

Post variables from request 1 device one
Processing....
Returning to device one...

Post variables from request 2 device two
Processing...
Returning to device two..

Now, as the number of simultaneous requests increase, the client machines keep getting timeout errors.

Is there any way in which I could process N number of requests simultaneously (if not all)?

Comment: Your heavy computation is probably blocking the event loop, so the next request will only get handled once the computation has completed. You need to offload the computation somehow.

Comment: @robertklep: Thanks for the insight. I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the coding approach that I have taken. Basically I have created a server using https, then process entities and end the request.

Comment: Also, is there any way that I can offload the computation? I mean,even I'd some other server does the heavy computation(server2), server1 will have to wait for server2 to return something and then return it to the client

Comment: And is there anyway that I could make it nonblocking , maybe run it in background till it is complete and process second request till then?

Comment: It completely depends on how your request handler is implemented, of course. Node by itself is able to process concurrent requests problemlessly, unless something is blocking its ability to accept new requests. Waiting for (network, file, process) I/O is not blocking, so it will allow Node to continue processing new requests while it's waiting for responses from another server.

Comment: I am requesting data from multiple websites in that processing part. Is that blocking by nature?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be blocking (it's network-I/O).